# How to add new option in select2 through RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I need to add one dummy option in an existing select2 tag through **RSpec.**

I am using the 'capybara-select2' gem, but it did not find any method to add a new option.

Comment: Could you give your use-case showing why you want to modify a select box in a test? This seems counter-intuitive

Answer (score 0):

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

```
var data = {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Barn owl'
};

var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
$('#mySelect2').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```

That's how you add options to a select2 instance.

Comment: appreciate you for your solution but you have given solution in jquery. I have mentioned already in question itself, i need to do in RSPec.

Comment: What do you mean with "in rspec", rspec is a testing framework, select2 is a jquery javascript plugin. What you can do is run that jquery code using capybara scripting inside your web driver https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#scripting. You'll need that javascript code somewhere, capybara-select2 does not provide that method (it uses javacript internally though)